# How to get image from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get an image path from my database and display the image using HTML `<img>` .

I am saving image's path in mysql database but i can't understand what's wrong.

**HTML:**

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>image</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="image_loading.php" width="100" height="100">
    </body>

</html>
<br />
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpass     = "";
$dbname     = "m_beg";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpass, $dbname) or die();
$sql = "SELECT `image` FROM `music_table` where `id`=100";

$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
header("Location:image/jpg");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $row["image"];
}

?>
```

Comment: header("Location:image/jpg")? Why not header ("Content-type: image/jpeg")?

Comment: Either ways... header with a filename will not work.

Comment: Why that header?! Are you calling binary data from your DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just all wrong. It will try load an image named 'image_loading.php'.
The php returns an invalid header.

Instead use this, by including the php function with your html code, if that makes sense.

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>image</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <img src="<?php echo getfilename();?>" width="100" height="100">
    </body>

</html>
<br />
```

PHP

```
    <?php
function getfilename()
{
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpass     = "";
    $dbname     = "m_beg";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpass, $dbname) or die();
    $sql = "SELECT `image` FROM `music_table` where `id`=100";

    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
        return $row["image"];
    }
    return "";//error no image found
}
?>
```

Comment: My pleasure Ajay. However, if you find an answer useful all you have to do it give it an "up vote". If it is a correct answer that helped you resolve your problem you must mark it as correct (with the tick by the votes), otherwise it will remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            $title = $row["image"];

            echo "<img src=$title width='100' height='100'>";
        }
```

Comment: echo "<img src=$title width='100' height='100'>";  is for display the image

Answer (score 0):

Try relative URL path adding forward slash to the path:

```
<img src="/image_loading.php" width="100" height="100">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code..

```
<?php
  $dbhost     = "localhost";
  $dbusername = "root";
  $dbpass     = "";
  $dbname     = "m_beg";

   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpass, $dbname) or die();
   $sql = "SELECT `image` FROM `music_table` where `id`=100";

   $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
   header("Location:image/jpg");

   //change this from mysqli_fetch_array to mysqli_fetch_assoc
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $image=$row['image'];
    echo "<img src='$image'>";
}


?>
```